# Python webbrowser not functioning with GIS server

Tags: python, xml, server, gis, python-webbrowser

I am trying to write a code that will download all the data from a server which holds the .rar files about imaginary cadastrial particles for student projects. What I got for now is the query for the server which only needs to input a specific number of particle and access it as url to download the .rar file.

```
url = 'http://www.pg.geof.unizg.hr/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.0.0&service=wfs&&propertyname=broj,naziv_ko,kc_geom&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP&typename=gf:katastarska_cestica&filter=<Filter+xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><And><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>broj</PropertyName><Literal>1900/1</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>naziv_ko</PropertyName><Literal>Suma Striborova Stara (9997)</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></And></Filter>'
```

This is the "url" I want to open with the web browser module for a particle "1900/1" but this way I get an error:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

When I manually input this url it downloads the file without a problem.
What is the way I can make this python web application work?
I used a `webbrowser.open_new(url)` option which does not work.

Comment: Should there be an empty space between Stara and (9997)? I can't dl the file.

Comment: @AntonvBR no. it's a valid link.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool. `webbrowser` is for controlling a native web browser. If you just want to download a file, use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module (or [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) if you can't install Requests).

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.pg.geof.unizg.hr/geoserver/wfs', params={
    'request': 'getfeature',
    ...
    'filter': '<Filter xmlns=...>'
})
print(r.content) # or write it to a file, or whatever
```

Note `requests` will handle encoding GET parameters for you -- you don't need to worry about escaping the request yourself.

Comment: thanks, i got this part working, but how can i get a .rar file as an output? It is automatically downloaded when you reach this link, so that's why I tried with webbrowser module.